Is the Wigner function non-negative only for convex mixtures of Gaussian states?
Hudson's theorem, the result usually cited in this context, tells us that for a pure state, the Wigner is non-negative iff the state is Gaussian, but doesn't in general say anything about mixed states.
Given the linear relation between a state and its Wigner function, we can infer that if a state is a convex mixture of Gaussian states, then its Wigner function remains non-negative.
Is the opposite also true? Can we say that in general the Wigner function is non-negative if and only if the state is a convex mixture of Gaussian states? Or in other words, that the negativity of the Wigner precisely corresponds to a state being outside the convex hull of Gaussian states?
I would think that this has to be the case if there's a linear bijection between density matrices and Wigner functions. But I haven't seen this stated explicitly, so I'm not sure whether this actually holds.
